# How to represent data from JSON in GridView ( table )

Tags: dojo, dijit.form, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have JSON file like this format

```
{
    "Alarms":[

    ],
    "BAE":[

    ],
    "Open":[

    ],
    "Timeout":[
        2,3,4,5,6,7,9
    ],
    "End Switches":[

    ],
    "Bus Power":[

    ],
    "External Power":[
        1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
    ]
}
```

where Alarms, BAE, Open... are  columns . I need to represent like GridView in ASP.NET ( like table  with pagination ). How to do that using Dojo ? Is there any widget which automatic represent  JSON file in table form ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Put your json data into a [data
   store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore.html#dojo-data-itemfilereadstore)
2. Bind the data store to
   a grid widget

Since you need pagination, you should use the [dojox.grid.Enhanced](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid.html#dojox-grid-enhancedgrid) widget and enable [pagination](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Pagination.html#dojox-grid-enhancedgrid-plugins-pagination).
Dojo does not offer a simple HTML table-from-json widget that also supports pagination.